# SSD can't be seen/formatted/anything , stops other drives from booting

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, ssd, formatting

I have an old SSD I once installed Win 7 on. As far as I remember the install was working fine at the time.

I booted the PC in question up again recently - it contains the SSD in question as well as a regular HDD which also has Win 7 installed.

However, now the HDD refuses to boot if the SSD is connected, regardless of what boot priority I set in BIOs.

Trying to boot from the SSD doesn't work, it takes an age of looking at the "Starting Windows" screen before either restarting or giving as "insert bootable media" message.

Having only the HDD connected means it boots fine. Having only the SSD connected gives the same error as above. As mentioned above I've tried different bios boot priority settings, and also tried swapping the SATA cables on the drives.

Hoping to simply reformat the SSD, I booted into Ubuntu from a USB. Here at least the SSD was visible (which it wasn't via 'list disk' in the command prompt via windows install disk, despite being visible in BIOS).
However I was unable to mount it, and any attempts at formatting/erasing etc just gave a variety of input/ouput errors.

At this stage I just want any possible way of wiping this thing so I can try and start fresh, provided the drive itself isn't just broken somehow since not being used for a few months having been fine.

So, any ideas?

Comment: The SSD sounds dead.

Comment: If so should I be entitled to a replacement under warranty you think?

Comment: Depends on cause of damage. If you damaged it by touching it (Electrostatic Discharge) or by dropping then I'm sorry to say, no you will not receive a replacement. I have experienced soemthing very similar with an external HDD (it may not be the same here, as your problem is an SSD). The HDD was in fact dead (mostly). It sorta worked in the same way your SSD works (detected by BIOS, sometimes visible to OS, rarely could open it and read/write).

Comment: Some damage is difficult to see unless it's opened, and the warranty terms depend entirely on the vendor. Give it a try though - no harm in asking.

Comment: Run http://www.hdsentinel.com/ for your SSD, It will show you the health of it.